Laravel 11 WARN could not find driver (Connection: sqlite, SQL: PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;)
I am a beginner I just start learning Laravel 11 . whenever  I download Laravel project the command show me.
WARN  could not find driver (Connection: SQLite, SQL: PRAGMA foreign keys = ON;).
enter image description here
and than I command
php artisan serve
the browser show me
enter image description here
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
could not find driver
PRAGMA foreign keys = ON;
I don't know what to do please someone help me
I just expect that my project get start no error show when I command php artisan serve the browser show Laravel theme  just it.

Is SQLite enabled in your php.ini

yes its enable .

In a fresh Laravel installation, check your session driver in the .env file.
If you want to use a database session driver, use these values (these are the default ones)
SESSION_DRIVER=database
And configure the connection to the database with these variables
DB_CONNECTION=
DB_HOST=
DB_PORT=
DB_DATABASE=
DB_USERNAME=
DB_PASSWORD=
If you are testing, or creating a development environment, just set the session driver value to File
SESSION_DRIVER=file
For more information about session handling in laravel check the official docs: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/session
